# Whitespace in Java's regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, whitespace

I'm trying to write a regular expression to mach an IRC PRIVMSG string. It is something like:

```
:nick!name@some.host.com PRIVMSG #channel :message body
```

So i wrote the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^:.*\\sPRIVMSG\\s#.*\\s:");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

It does not work. I got no matches. When I test the regular expression using online javascript testers, I got matches.

I tried to find the reason, why it doesn't work and I found that there's something wrong with the whitespace symbol. The following pattern will give me some matches:

```
Pattern.compile("^:.*");
```

But the pattern with \s will not:

```
Pattern.compile("^:.*\\s");
```

It's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java `matches` method strikes again!  That method only returns true if the *entire* string matches the input. You didn't include anything that captures the message body after the second colon, so the *entire* string is not a match.  It works in testers because 'normal' regex is a 'match' if any part of the input matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^:.*?\\sPRIVMSG\\s#.*?\\s:.*$");
```

Should match

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), uou will notice that it is trying to match the **entire** string. You need to fix your regexp or use `find()` to iterate through the substring matches.